# How do I set up a ViewPage and it's Adapter in android?

Tags: android-viewpager, android-adapter, viewpage

Im trying to learn about how to set up sliding tabs on my app's custom 'Toolbar' using material design. As I understand it, I'll need a 'ViewPage', does that mean i need to create a 'ViewPager', and set its 'Adapter'? Which I suppose will populate my fragment views with the relevant data. Can someone help explain how to go about doing this?

I'm only planning to use two tabs.

So far i have my xml which I got from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRg_eDfQ8fk , it looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

<com.example.android.common.view.slidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That video is seriously outdated. Tab layouts are now a part of the new Design Support library, you should look into them. See [Google's blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) for a kickstart.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure it out. I'm posting the article that helped me in case anyone also needs to solve the problem.

http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

The Article talks about setting up the tabs after setting up the toolbar (Which they also link to) and how to set up your fragments as well. Really useful.